# basic Haskell : list comprehension

Tags: haskell

Me again, I'm trying to iterate through my list of customers to find the correct customer and when I find them I want to display any non-zero int's that are attached to them. I'm not sure how to proceed. I know there will only be 1 record of the person's name in the shop.

```
type Name = String
type Customer = (Name,Int,Int)
type Shop = [Customer]
shop = [cust1, cust2]

cust1 = ("Steve", 321, 123) :: Customer
cust2 = ("John", 0,678) :: Customer

getName :: Customer -> Name
getName (a, b,c) = a

getNumbers :: Customer -> [Int]
getNumbers (a,b,c) = filter (/=0) [b,c] 


rental:: Shop-> Name -> [Int]
rental shop' name' = map getNumbers [ x|x<-shop',getName x == name']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is pretty close.  First of all, you need to update `getName` to take a 3-tuple, and second you should use `concatMap getNumbers` instead of `map getNumbers`.

Although, it looks like you're going to be adding new fields to your `Customer` type, so I would recommend that you switch to using a record instead:

```
data Customer = Customer
    { custName :: Name
    , custVal1 :: Int  -- I don't know what these are, so use real names
    , custVal2 :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And now you could get rid of `getName` and do

```
getNumbers :: Customer -> [Int]
getNumbers c = filter (/= 0) [custVal1 c, custVal2 c]

rental :: Shop -> Name -> [Int]
rental shop' name' = concatMap getNumbers [x | x <- shop', custName x == name']
```

Now if you were to add another field to `Customer`, you don't have to update all your functions that don't depend on that field.

Answer (score 4):

It is very useful to read error message!

```
test23.hs:10:9:
    Couldn't match type `(Name, t0)' with `(Name, Int, Int)'
    Expected type: Customer
      Actual type: (Name, t0)
```

You have

```
getName (a, b) = a
```

but is defined

```
type Customer = (Name,Int,Int)
```

The right function looks like

```
getName (a, _, _) = a
```

After correct, you could see next meassage:

```
test23.hs:17:26:
    Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Int'
    Expected type: Customer -> Int
      Actual type: Customer -> [Int]
    In the first argument of `map', namely `getNumbers'
    ...
    In an equation for `rental'
```

But error is not in `getNumbers`, but in signature of `rental:: Shop-> Name -> [Int]`. Must be:

```
rental:: Shop-> Name -> [[Int]]
```

Comment: Thanks but the real problem is with the rental algorithm. I'm not sure how to print out the non-zero elements at the same time as checking the name is the same as the input.